# Image Button property to popup new window

Tags: asp.net, image, button, properties

Below is my sample code that already done, unfortunately the the popup window doesn't has min & max icon on right top of the window.  It just close icon only and it appear maximum of the screen size.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server"         
    ImageUrl="images/icon_edit_moderator.gif" 
    OnClientClick="window.showModalDialog('search_staffM.aspx?id=document.forms[0].<%=Marketer_Staff_ID.clientID%>&id2=document.forms[0].<%=Marketer_Staffname.clientID%>','Search','width=550,height=170,left=150,top=200,scrollbars=1,toolbar=no,status=1')" /></td>
```

Comment: try..>> &id2=document.forms[0].<%=Marketer_Staffname.clientID%>','Search','width=550,height=170,left=150,top=200,scrollbars=1,toolbar=no,resizable=yes, status=1')" />

Comment: Two things:
1) You should format your html markup using [these instructions ][1]
2) You should actually ask a question. Right now you simply state the current status of your problem and are leaving us to guess what you want.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for `window.open()` instead of `window.showModalDialog()`

Also, you aren't correctly concatenating the form field value into the url parameter of the method. Try the code below.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server"         
    ImageUrl="images/icon_edit_moderator.gif" 
    OnClientClick="window.open('search_staffM.aspx?id='+ document.forms[0].<%=Marketer_Staff_ID.ClientID %> +'&id2='+ document.forms[0].<%=Marketer_Staffname.clientID%>,'Search','width=550,height=170,left=150,top=200,scrollbars=1,toolbar=no,status=1')" /></td>
```

For a different, perhaps cleaner, approach I would suggest creating a separate javascript function and then use the OnClientClick to call it.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function openStaffDetails() {
    var url = "search_staffM.aspx?id=" + document.forms[0].<%=Marketer_Staff_ID.ClientID %> + "&id2=" + document.forms[0].<%=Marketer_Staffname.clientID%>;
    window.open(url, 'Search','width=550,height=170,left=150,top=200,scrollbars=1,toolbar=no,status=1');
    return false;
  }
</script>

<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server"         
    ImageUrl="images/icon_edit_moderator.gif" 
    OnClientClick="return openStaffDetails();" /></td>
```